# Can't login on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, login, kali-linux

I have used kali for a year now and it was working perfectly. Yesterday I ran an install script, logged out and when I tried to log in it tells me that the password is incorrect. I know that that's the right password, I even tried changing it from another account but it still says that it's incorrect. I can log into **any other account**, but it doesn't allow me to log in as root.

Comment: @Krizan 0596 You can try typing `sudo -i` from an administrator account and the enter the password of the administrator account in the terminal to make it run as root until you find a proper solution. I can provide only this small help.

Comment: Please read [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)